# Is a Child Born to Jewish Mother and Father Outside of Marriage a Mamzer?

Tags: halacha, mamzer

I was reading that a child born to a married Jewish mother to a father who is not her husband is a Mamzer (bastard). But what if the parents are both Jewish, neither of them are married but they have a child together?

What is the child considered in that case? Still a mamzer?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71768/does-marrying-the-woman-one-got-pregnant-before-the-baby-is-born-make-a-differen

Answer (score 6):

No.

The rule is stated in Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 4, 13:

> איזהו ממזר? זה הבא מאחת מכל העריות, בין בחייבי מיתות בין בחייבי כריתות, חוץ מהבא מהנדה, שאף על פי שהוא פגום, אינו ממזר אפילו מדרבנן:‏
>
> Who is Mamzer.?  He who is born from one of the prohibited relatioship between Jewish persons,  which is punishable by Karet or death, except nidda {which is punishable by Karet and does not lead to mamzerut} ....

Additionally if one of the parents is mamzer.

A relationship without marriage with a celibate woman is not allowed, but this is not categorized as a relationship which leads to mamzerut in  offspring  See  SA EH 26, 1.

Comment: I think 4:26 is a better source to cite as it addresses our case explicitly. פנויה שנתעברה וילדה... ואם אותו פלוני הוא כשר, הולד כשר

Comment: @DoubleAA yes but the point is that we follow the rov and the Chezkat kashrut,  the original din penuya is in 26