# Child born out of wedlock

Tags: mamzer

Is there any negative implication or any negative result from a child that was born out of wedlock from 2 jewish parents? On a follow up question to that, would there be any difference if the parents marry subsequent to (1) the mother finding out that she is pregnant? (2) the child being born? My question not only relates to halachik impact and restriction but even as it relates to customs, yichus, and how the child would be viewed by even the strictest of authorities on any level whatsoever.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79823/is-a-child-born-to-jewish-mother-and-father-outside-of-marriage-a-mamzer

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yanky. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: related: [Does marrying the woman one got pregnant before the baby is born make a difference?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71768/11501)

Comment: related: [What problems are faced by children born out of wedlock?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29784/what-problems-are-faced-by-children-born-out-of-wedlock)

Comment: I marked is as a clear duplicate. Please specify if the " What problems are faced by children born out of wedlock?" does not answer your question.

Comment: Note Ben/Bas niddah can come into this.

Comment: If the parents are not forbidden to marry due to an issur lav, the child is kosher. I assume you're asking after the fact, otherwise, don't do it; it's just plain stupid(not to mention karet if they don't do teshuva). There would also be a spiritual taint of being a ben/bat niddah; but still eligible to marry into the Jewish nation. It's best for both parents to marry each other, if they love each other and it's a match. Ask a rabbi, though. Don't rely on me.